# Google+ API - Pass User Email in Query String

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, node.js, google-plus

I want to pass the name and email of the logged in Google+ API user into my URL. I have the following link on my web page:

```
<a href="http://10.2.114.243/Default.aspx?name=<%= user.givenName %>&email=<%= user.email %>">Create Project</a>
```

This passes the user's first name into the URL just fine. However, I cannot, despite much googling, determine what the value is for getting the user's email. I found Google's [People Reference](http://%20https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people) documentation and tried different combinations:

- `emails[0].value`
- `emails[].value`
- `emails.value`
- `value`

but each time, the value is passed in the query string as `undefined` or throws an error.

I was told I need to figure out what the JSON value is for the user's email.

Comment: `href="http://10.2.114.243/Default.aspx?name=John?email=undefined"`

Comment: If I try `user.emails[0].value` or `user.emails[].value` I get a `TypeError`. "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: actually, ignore me, I'm having a bad day - `user.givenName` suggests your .net `user` object is the `name` part of the data structure, therefore, without seeing what you do in .net ... guessing game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it ended up needing to be `user._json.email`. The following is my final code, in case it helps anyone

```
<% if (user != 1) { %>
        <% var firstName = user.displayName 
        firstName = firstName.substring(0, firstName.indexOf('\ '));
        %>
        <a href="http://192.168.165.100/Default.aspx?name=<%= firstName %>&email=<%= user._json.email %>">Create Project</a>
<% } %>
```